# Will Ethanol degrade Silicone or "RTV" specifically "RTV 734", or cause it to "leach" ingredients at temperatures below 250 degrees farenheit?

Tags: materials, reaction-control

Will Ethanol degrade Silicone or "RTV" specifically [RTV 734](http://www.dowcorning.de/applications/search/products/default.aspx?R=407DE&country=USA), a flowable sealant produced by *Dow Corning*, or cause it to "leach" ingredients at temperatures below 250 degrees Fahrenheit?

Such as in the distilling process.

Thanks!