Appropriate transparent, gasoline-resistant plastic
I want to make a sight glass (a transparent level gauge) for an E10 ethanol/gasoline tank. For informal use, vinyl tubing is often used, although the vinyl degrades and needs to be replaced regularly.
Is there a more appropriate transparent plastic which is resistant to ethanol-containing gasoline?
For steam boilers, glass tubing has been used but in this application it would be too fragile.

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71376/will-ethanol-degrade-silicone-or-rtv-specifically-rtv-734-or-cause-it-to-l

because I think silicone tubing would do here.

Glass is actually stronger than steel. If suitably mounted (e.g., supported by multiple gasoline-resistant O-rings), a thick-walled borosilicate glass tube would likely be sturdier than any organic plastic.
